# An Error occured while parsing EntityName. Line 32, position 51

Tags: c#, xml

I've tried looking at several different methods revolving around using XDocument class to load my xml file. However, this error and other variations have been appearing. If I use the absolute path, it displays an error of it cannot find the file.
The issue is my xml file has a combination of both English and Japanese used in it. The link should allow for anyone to view the xml file.

Here is my code and xml file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string URLSource = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh3bfzvhpj6e3x1/JapanseEnglish.xml?dl=0";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XMLViewer();
    }

    private void XMLViewer()
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load(URLSource);
            var Kanji = from WordList in Doc.Descendants("Kanji")
                        select new
                        {
                            Word = WordList.Element("Kanji").Value
                        };

            foreach (var Word in Kanji)
            {
                JpnTxt.ItemsSource = Word.ToString();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That file has 24 lines, not sure why it's complaining about line 32.

Comment: You can not use dropbox link cause its not contains pure XML. It's HTML page just working as XML Viewer

Comment: Yes, but adding parameter `dl=1` instead of `dl=0` resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you use don't contain a XML document but an HTML page :
`https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh3bfzvhpj6e3x1/JapanseEnglish.xml?dl=0`

You need to change the value of `dl` to 1, so Dropbox will return your XML document:
`https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh3bfzvhpj6e3x1/JapanseEnglish.xml?dl=1`

Comment: For downvoters, it's an answer to: "If I use the absolute path, it displays an error of it cannot find the file."

Comment: Also, OP probably wants `Word = WordList.Value` since `WordList` is already an element named `"Kanji"`.

Comment: Florian's answer has definitely helped resolve that error. Now all I have to do is fix the encoding.

Comment: Here the link is not important. It's the first argument. The link don't contain the answer. The link is the answer.
A part of the answer...

Comment: Well, I'd say that the "link is the answer" for *all* link-only answers. Isn't it true that I have to click on these links to "get" the answer? Links that may be dead tomorrow and cease to "give" an answer. I'd be willing to give the rep back if you edited the links out and explained, in words, *why* this must be done. The link that downloads a file to a user's machine is worth -2 IMHO.

Comment: Maybe my answer is not clear. You don't have to click on the link. My answer is that his link don't return a XML document but an HTML page. So, what I said in my post is that he need to change the last parameter in the URL. I don't want peoples click on it... I'm clear or not? I just edit it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Florian said you should use second link, but maybe you have problem to read unicode xml, so its better using Request and ResponseStream:

```
private string URLSource = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh3bfzvhpj6e3x1/JapanseEnglish.xml?dl=1";

private void XMLViewer()
{
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLSource);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, true))
                {
                    XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
                    var Kanji = from WordList in Doc.Descendants("Kanji")
                                select new
                                {
                                    Word = WordList.Element("Kanji").Value
                                };

                    foreach (var Word in Kanji)
                    {                            
                        JpnTxt.ItemsSource = Word.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
     }

     catch (Exception e)
     {               
           MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
     }
}
```